# Can you use 'fscanf' to read in individual chars and an int?

Tags: c, file, scanf

I am trying to convert some code that reads in three integers per line of txt file til end of file.
ie:

```
int int int
int int int
int int int
```

What I am trying to get it to do now is read in is:

```
z z 5
z z 6
z z 5
```

til end of file.

I'm having an issue right after it opens the file. I placed several debuggers to track the progress and I commented what is printed. It only shows the before and after of the first line of the file. So I'm guessing it is only reading one line.

```
        int i,origin,destin,wt;
        char a, b;
        int nodes = 0;
        
        printf("before file is opened\n"); // displayed

        FILE *fptr = fopen("input.txt","r");

        printf("after file is opened\n"); // displayed

        while (fscanf(fptr, "%c %c %d", &a, &b, &wt) == 3){
            
            printf("\before is : %c %c\n", a, b);  // shows the first line of file   
            origin = convertToNum(a);
            destin = convertToNum(b);
            
            printf("\nconversion is : %d %d\n", origin, destin); // 1st line of file shown
        }
```

*edit*
Changing:

```
while (fscanf(fptr, "%c %c %d", &a, &b, &wt) == 3)
```

to:

```
while (fscanf(fptr, "%c %c %d", &a, &b, &wt) != EOF)
```

Produces slightly better results. It will read in one line just fine.
Every other line seems to have a whitespace issue.

Comment: First of all, unlike e.g. `%d` the `%c` format does not skip leading white-space. Secondly, if the file contains the actual `'` characters those aren't handled by the `%c` format, it just reads the next actual character from the input source.

Comment: I bet it doesn't actually stop where you put that comment. Your `while` loop just never executes because `fscanf` never returns 3 in your case. But that depends on the input, and you haven't posted that.

Comment: 1)  Test if `fptr== NULL` after the `fopen()`,  2) Try `"%c %c %d"` --> `" %c %c %d"`.  Add space.

Comment: I posted what the input looks like. It doesn't have single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize %c also grabbed newline characters.

```
char buf[512];
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fptr) != 0) {
        sscanf(buf, "%c %c %d", &a, &b, &wt);
```